# Rate limits for NIST API

Tags: python, rate-limiting

Essentially I am trying to query the NIST API using a CPE, to collect all the vulnerabilities about that CPE using python. The NIST documentation says if you have an API key (which I do) you get 100 requests in a rolling 60 second window, but when I only make 24 requests using aiohttp, asyncrnously I get a 403 forbidden error, with the text stating Request forbidden by administrative rules. The documentation also states you should "sleep" your scripts for six seconds between requests. So my question is how many requests should I send as those statements seem to be contradicting one another. And why am I getting this error?

Comment: This is really a question for the owners of the API.

Comment: @MattDMo Wish i knew those people

Comment: At the bottom of the National Vulnerabilities Database page (the page describing the NVD/CPE API - https://nvd.nist.gov/developers/products) is this line: "*Questions, comments, or concerns may be shared with the NVD by emailing nvd@nist.gov*". Took me one Google query (`nist api cpe`) and less than 30 seconds to find that.

Answer (score 1):

The public rate limit is 5 requests in a rolling 30 second window. That means you need to have a sleep time of 6 secs between requests.

In the case you have an API key, you are allowed to make 50 requests in a rolling 30 second window. That is approx. 2 requests per second without needing to sleep. If you plan to make more requests in the allowed 30 second window, then you may have to implement an appropriate sleep time.

Comment: Where you get this information from?

Answer (score 0):

See https://nvd.nist.gov/developers/start-here

**Rate Limits**

NIST firewall rules put in place to prevent denial of service attacks can thwart your application if it exceeds a predetermined rate limit. The public rate limit (without an API key) is 5 requests in a rolling 30 second window; the rate limit with an API key is 50 requests in a rolling 30 second window. Requesting an API key significantly raises the number of requests that can be made in a given time frame. However, it is still recommended that your application sleeps for several seconds between requests so that legitimate requests are not denied, and all requests are responded to in sequence.

UPDATE:

> So my question is how many requests should I send as those statements
> seem to be contradicting one another.

I would recommend that you try various wait periods until you find one that works best for you. If 6 seconds, doesn't work, try 10 seconds.

> And why am I getting this error?

You're getting the error because you're exceeding their API limits.